# CSS Selector Change

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have created a html/css template to be used within a CMS.

I have a specific class:

**My Template:**

```
<li><a class="signup" href="#">SIGN UP</a></li>
```

**CMS Generated HTML:**

```
<li class="signup last"> 

        <a href="http://hostone.co.nz">SIGN UP</a> 
    </li>
```

How could I change my CSS so it will work with the `li` and not the `a` tag?

**CSS:**

```
#mainMenu .signup{
    background-color:#69c21c;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:360px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:2px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:2px;
}

#mainMenu .signup:hover{
    background-color:#00afd8;
}
```

Comment: If it's acting on the CMS generated markup, then it should already be applied to the li.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're still trying to apply the rules to the `a`, use these:

```
#mainMenu .signup a {
    background-color:#69c21c;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:360px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:2px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:2px;
}

#mainMenu .signup a:hover {
    background-color:#00afd8;
}
```

If you're literally trying to apply them to the `li`, you don't need to do anything; the `li` is already being generated with the class.